# JPanel is not updating

Tags: java, swing

I have two panels. One of them is GamePanel and the other one is ControlPanel. When I press the launch button (which is added in the ControlPanel) the ball starts moving until it hits something. I have score, time and level labels in the ControlPanel and I expect them to update during the game but they don't.

### ControlPanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    public static JLabel timeValue, scoreValue, levelValue;
    public static JButton launch;

    public static Timer timer;

    ControlPanel() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBounds(0, 600, 1200, 200);
    }

    public void addUnits() {

        launch = new JButton("Launch");
        launch.setBounds(450, 70, 90, 65);

        launch.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            int start = 0;

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (ControlPanel.launch.getModel().isPressed()) {

                    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            timeValue.setText(++start + " sec");
                        }
                    };

                    timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
                    timer.setRepeats(true);
                    timer.start();

                    GamePanel.ball.moveBall();
                }
            }
        });

        add(launch);

        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Time");
        timeLabel.setBounds(615, 70, 90, 25);
        add(timeLabel);

        timeValue = new JLabel("0 sec");
        timeValue.setBounds(690, 70, 90, 25);
        add(timeValue);

        JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score");
        scoreLabel.setBounds(605, 110, 90, 25);
        add(scoreLabel);

        scoreValue = new JLabel(String.valueOf(Score.score));
        scoreValue.setBounds(690, 110, 90, 25);
        add(scoreValue);

        JLabel levelLabel = new JLabel("Level");
        levelLabel.setBounds(800, 110, 90, 25);
        add(levelLabel);

        levelValue = new JLabel(String.valueOf(GamePanel.status));
        levelValue.setBounds(860, 110, 90, 25);
        add(levelValue);
    }
}
```

This is my moveBall method

```
public void moveBall() {

    // calculate move       

    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            // initiate move

            if(hit()) {
                ControlPanel.timer.stop();

                level = getLevel() + 1;
                score = // calculate score;

                timer.stop();

                ControlPanel.levelValue.setText(String.valueOf(level));
                ControlPanel.scoreValue.setText(String.valueOf(score));

                ControlPanel.levelValue.revalidate();
                ControlPanel.scoreValue.revalidate();

                ControlPanel.levelValue.repaint();
                ControlPanel.scoreValue.repaint();
            }

            paintingComponent.repaint();
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(10, taskPerformer);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: I don't really remember how to solve it, but the thing is that repaint() is not enough. I'll check what needs to be done.

Comment: You don't need revalidate() and you don't need repaint(). Whenever you change a property of a Swing component the component will repaint itself. So the only code you need is the `setText(...)` method. So now if the code is executed and if the component was added to the GUI then the text on the label will be updated. So add debug code. Display the values of your "level" and "score" to make sure the code is updated and the value changes.

Comment: Also, you should NOT 1)  be using static variables., 2) use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, Typically you would use an ActionLIstener on a JButton not a ChangeListener.